# Why is this persistent actor not working

Tags: scala, akka

Here is the code:

```
import akka.persistence._
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem, Props, ActorLogging}


class Counter extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {

  import Counter._

  var state: State = new State(0)

  override def receiveRecover: Receive = {
    case RecoveryCompleted => println("Recovery completed.")
    case SnapshotOffer(_, snapshot: State) => state = snapshot
    case op: Operation => updateState(op)
  }


  override def persistenceId: String = "counter-persistent"

  override def receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case op: Operation =>
      println(s"Counter receive ${op}")
      persist(op) {
        op => updateState(op)
      }
    case "print" => println(s"The current state of couter is ${state}")
    case SaveSnapshotFailure(_, reason) => println(s"save snapshot failed, reason: ${reason}")
    case SaveSnapshotSuccess(_) => println(s"snapshot saved")
  }

  def updateState(op: Operation): Unit = op match {
    case Increment(n) =>
      state = state.inc(n)
      takeSnapshot
    case Decrement(n) =>
      state = state.dec(n)
      takeSnapshot
  }

  def takeSnapshot: Unit = {
    //    if (state % 5 == 0) saveSnapshot()
    saveSnapshot()
  }
}


object Counter {

  sealed trait Operation {
    val count: Int
  }

  case class Increment(override val count: Int) extends Operation

  case class Decrement(override val count: Int) extends Operation

  final case class State(n: Int) {
    def inc(x: Int) = State(n + x)

    def dec(x: Int) = State(n - x)
  }

}







object Persistent extends App {

  import Counter._

  val system = ActorSystem("persistent-actors")

  val counter = system.actorOf(Props[Counter])

  counter ! Increment(3)
  counter ! Increment(5)
  counter ! Decrement(3)
  counter ! "print"

  Thread.sleep(1000)

  system.terminate()

}
```

Configuration (application.conf):

```
akka {
  persistence {
    journal {
      plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb",
      leveldb {
        dir = "target/example/journal",
        native = false
      }
    },
    snapshot-store {
      plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local",
      local {
        dir = "target/example/snapshots"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Running the app twice shows that the state is not persistent at all:

```
Recovery completed.
Counter receive Increment(3)
Counter receive Increment(5)
Counter receive Decrement(3)
The current state of couter is State(5)
snapshot saved
snapshot saved
snapshot saved

Recovery completed.
Counter receive Increment(3)
Counter receive Increment(5)
Counter receive Decrement(3)
The current state of couter is State(5)
snapshot saved
snapshot saved
snapshot saved
```

Why?

Comment: Have you configured the persistence plugin? Which journal are you using?

Comment: What is the problem you are facing what is not working. Please, provide more info on this.

Comment: @manub Configuration now posted.

Comment: @curious Details added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that you are taking snapshot after every operation message the actor receives but while taking snapshot you are not saving its state. If you closely look at you takeSnapshot code:

```
def takeSnapshot: Unit = {
    //    if (state % 5 == 0) saveSnapshot()
    saveSnapshot()
  }
```

the call to `saveSnapshot()` does not take a snapshot of your state as there is no argument passed to it.

you need to modify you `takeSnapshot` method a bit like this:

```
  def takeSnapshot: Unit = {
    //    if (state % 5 == 0) saveSnapshot()
    saveSnapshot(state) // Pass the states you need to store while taking a snapshot.
  }
```

This will work.